# Node.js Sequelize dependency problem

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am working with node.js (0.4.7) with sequelize library (1.0.2). npm set the dependencies so that

```
 ─┬ sequelize@1.0.2 
│ ├── lingo@0.0.4 
│ ├─┬ mysql@0.9.3 
│ │ └─┬ hashish@0.0.4 
│ │   └── traverse@0.5.1 
│ ├── underscore@1.1.7 
│ └── underscore.string@1.1.6
```

However, the node.js gives an error

```
node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: deprecated: use mysql.createClient() instead
    at new Client (/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/mysql/lib/client.js:12:11)
```

I googled it and I just found: https://github.com/sdepold/sequelize/issues/89 which does not solve my problem. It is an apparently dependency problem. Does anyone of you have faced this problem before? Any idea how to solve it?

Node.js is running on a Ubuntu 9.04 on an ARM processor.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's basically sequelize using deprecated API and you need to fix sequelize

Comment: read the mysql docs and figure out what the correct alternative it, patch it. run the unit tests for sequelize to check you havnt broken it then make a pull request for sequelize

Comment: hey there. I'm very sorry for don't fixing that. Will try to get some time to do so. Maybe this afternoon/evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I just released v1.1.0 which supports node-mysql 0.9.4. Please give it a try and tell me if it works nicely for you.